# how to run async code before sync code in combination with form

Tags: angular, asynchronous, indexeddb

so far I have a form, where I could save some data in an indexedDB (e.g. a list of names) and display them as a list. When I click on the entry of that list another form opens, where I can edit the name I've clicked on. the second form should exactly look like the first one except that the input section isn't empty but filled with the name I've clicked on.

my Form needs sync code (as far as I know)

```
myForm = new Formgroup({
    name: newFormControl('',[Validators.required])
});
```

my first try was:

```
ngOnInit() {
    db.list.get({id: 1}, temp => this.names = temp);
    this.myForm.patchValue({name: this.names.name});
}
```

but get is async and resolves after patchValue so nothing happens.

So I've tried:

```
ngOnInit() {
    db.list.get({id: 1}).then( function(names){
        this.myForm.patchValue({name: names.name});
    });
}
```

but then myForm is unknown an if I declare myForm at that point my Form is unhappy because it's not declared.

Now I`ve run out of ideas.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: there are about 1 million ways to work this out, one of them would be to use `async` `await`. another one would be to initialize myForm with a null value, and when `indexdb` fetches the value, patch it up. in the meanwhile i'd show a loading spinner or such to prevent user from interacting with the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `await` keyword

```
async ngOnInit() {
    const value = await db.list.get({id: 1}, temp => this.names = temp);
    this.myForm.patchValue({name: this.value.name});
}
```